# Error before data is loaded using Tanstack Query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am trying to retrieve some data from my backend by using:

```
const fetchData = useQuery(["myData", year, month, day, hour], async () => {
    const response = await axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/api/data_calc`, {
        year: year,
        month: month,
        day: day,
        hour: hour,
    });     
    return response.data;

});

const { data, error, isLoading } = fetchData;
```

I then use the `data` prop in my component, such as:

```
return (
    <div>{data.val1}</div>
)
```

However, my issue is, that by fetching the `data.val1`, at initial load, there isn't any `data` available, and I get an error. I know I could probably use the `isLoading` prop, and return a `Is Loading...` instead of the div, but my issue with that is that I don't want that loading screen afterwards. Like, I just want it to show the former `data.val1` until it is updated. No need to show a `Is loading` until the new fetch has arrived.

How can I accomplish that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set `keepPreviousData: true` to keep `data` when the `queryKey` changes:

- https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/paginated-queries#better-paginated-queries-with-keeppreviousdata